# how to define a setter on existing object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to define a setter for existing object property in javascript ES6 concept.
Currently, I've directly assigned the value to true, I would like to achieve the same by using setter.

HTML:

```
<form #Form="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveForm()">
<label class="radio-inline pr-3">
<input type="radio" name="isCitizen" required value="yes [(ngModel)]="formList.isCitizen" #isCitizen="ngModel"> Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="isCitizen" required value="no"[(ngModel)]="formList.isCitizen"#isCitizen="ngModel"> No
</label>
<form>
```

Component:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
 })
 export class AppComponent  {
 name = 'Angular';
 formList: FormModel = new FormModel();

 saveForm(){ //how to set the value to object using setter
 if(this.formList.isCitizen === 'yes'){
 this.formList.isCitizen = true;
 }else{
 this.formList.isCitizen = false;
 }
 }
 }

 export class FormModel {
 isCitizen : boolean;
 }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czfzmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: What do you mean by "*using a setter*"? What should the setter do? Why do you think you need to use a setter?

Answer (score 0):

In typescript use

```
export class FormModel {
    private  _isCitizen : boolean;

    set isCitizen(isCitizen:boolean) {
        this._isCitizen = isCitizen;
    }
    get isCitizen():boolean {
       return this._isCitizen ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I totally get you on that one.